# использование массивов с циклами

Tags: c#, while

Хочу чтобы при каждой иттерации выводило новое значение из массива, а выводит только первый.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[,] madd = new string[2, 2];
        madd[0, 0] = "gh";
        madd[1, 0] = "gf";
        madd[1, 1] = "hfk";
        int m, k;
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (n < 1 && i < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(madd[n, i]
            );
            n++;
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `while (n  < = 1 && i < = 1)`

Comment: так условие цикла неверное плюс ты выводишь только главную диагонаь

Comment: спасибо,за ответ